# Class template based wrapping function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Let's assume we have to use several versions of the same old-style interface which consists of a set of functions. The difference between versions is in the naming convention and additional commonly used last argument in each function that we need to process after each function invocation. Something like

```
bool f1_v1(double a, int *common_arg);
// .....

bool fN_v1(double a, bool b, char c, int *common_arg);
```

Simple template based wrap looks like

```
template <typename T> struct wrapper;

template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
struct wrapper<_Res(_ArgTypes...)> {

    template <_Res (*f)(_ArgTypes...)>
    struct wrap {

        template <typename... Args> 
        _Res operator()(Args... args) {
            int common_arg;
            _Res res = f(args..., &common_arg);
            // common processing....
// .....

            return res;
        };
    };
};

wrapper<decltype(f1_v1)>::wrap<f1_v1> _f1;
// .....

wrapper<decltype(fN_v1)>::wrap<fN_v1> _fN;
```

It looks ugly, isn't it? And we still need macro to avoid double substitution of the function name.
Is there an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Anything starting with an underscore then a capital letter is a reserved identifier.  Don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, C++11 or C++14, I think you can only semplify the `wrapper` class, avoiding the inner `wrap` struct, using partial specialization as follows

```
template <typename T, T>
struct wrapper;

template <typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes, _Res (*f)(_ArgTypes...)>
struct wrapper<_Res(_ArgTypes...), f>
 {
   template <typename... Args> 
      _Res operator()(Args... args)
       {
         int common_arg;
         _Res res = f(args..., &common_arg);
         // common processing....

         return res;
       };
 };
```

So you can define and use `_f1` and `_fN` as follows

```
wrapper<decltype(f1_v1), f1_v1> _f1;
wrapper<decltype(fN_v1), fN_v1> _fN;

std::cout << _f1(0.1) << std::endl;
std::cout << _fN(0.1, true, 'c') << std::endl;
```

If you want define `_f1` and `_fN` as follows

```
wrapper<f1_v1> _f1;
wrapper<fN_v1> _fN;
```

you need a C++17 compliant compiler and the `auto` type for non-type template argument.

I don't have a C++17 compiler but I suppose that `wrapper` should be defined as follows

```
template <auto f>
struct wrapper
 {
   template <typename... Args> 
      _Res operator()(Args... args)
       {
         int common_arg;
         _Res res = f(args..., &common_arg);
         // common processing....

         return res;
       };
 };
```

Comment: Yep, this one looks better.
Also does not have C+17.
Thanks.